# Executing JavaScript functions in JSON using eval()

Tags: php, javascript, json

I want to execute any JavaScript function that is part of a JSON using eval() but obviously I can't do it right, and can't figure out where exactly is the mistake/s. I'm using two very simple files, just for trying - the first is index.php and is at it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple form sending and receiving a JSON object to/from PHP</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var data = 
  { 
    "sales": [ 
      { "firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Brown" },
      { "firstname" : "Marc", "lastname" : "Johnson" }
    ] // end of sales array
  }
  var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);

  $.post('simpleformSubmi.php', { data: dataString}, showResult, "text");
});

function showResult(res)
{
    var data = eval('(' + res + ')');

  $("#fullresponse").html("Full response: " +data);
}
</script>
<div id="fullresponse"></div>
</head>
<body>
```

and the second one is simpleformSubmi.php :

```
<?php

$logFile = 'logFile';
$res = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);
$arr = "function(){alert('Hi')}";
echo json_encode($res);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

So what I expected was after executing echo json_encode($arr); to get and alert but instead I get a mistake, and in Firebug the console shows error "missing ) in parenthetica". So the question is - how to send a valid JS function this way and to execute it properly?

Thanks
Leron

Comment: *"Executing JavaScript functions in JSON using `eval()`"* [JSON doesn't have functions. At all.](http://json.org) If you're including functions in your server response, then you're returning JavaScript code, not JSON. I don't think PHP's `json_encode` is going to pass them through (it *shouldn't*, but whether it *does* I don't know).

Comment: If you remove/comment out `echo json_encode($res)` and change `echo json_encode($arr)` to `echo $arr`, what happens?

Comment: Full response: function () { alert("Hi"); } - appears as plain HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you are `json_encode`ing $arr. You may just return it as a string `echo $arr` and `eval('(' + res + ')()')` in the JavaScript (notice the `()` in the JS to execute the function). You may need to remove `echo json_encode($res)` just to get this to work for now.

Comment: It still wouldn't run the function as the code would be `var data = eval("(function(){alert('Hi')})");` Though it must be better than trying to run (evaled version for clarity) `var data = (function(){alert('Hi')}{ ... })`

Comment: Esailija: No, the code will be `eval('(function(){alert('Hi')})()')`. Notice the `()` at the end. That make it [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A JSON object cannot contain functions, only values.

You will have to setup some sort of webservice that actually prints JavaScript, which you in turn can call through a `<script src="/your/endpoint"></script>` declaration client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the js function as data.

```
$data = array("something"=>"12345");
$js = "alert('hi!')";
$data["autoexec"] = $js;    
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then on the clientside do something like eval(data["autoexec"]);